# Objective-C calling a method from another method

Tags: objective-c

Say if i have a method as follows;

```
 - (void)carpentorLoad {
      NSlog(@"HI... Hello");
 }
```

Now, i need to call this method from another method, say `- (int) CallingMethod`

```
-(int) CallingMethod{
    // Here, i need to call carpentorLoad Method
   return 0;
}
```

How should i call `carpentorLoad` from `CallingMethod` do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these methods in the same class?  If so you can just do:

```
- (int) CallingMethod {
   [self carpentorLoad];
   return 0;
}
```

If they are in different classes, then you'll need to pass a reference to the second class into your calling method, like:

```
- (int) CallingMethod: (Carpentor*)theCarpentor {
   [theCarpentor carpentorLoad];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Either pass a reference or call a method/function that returns that reference (maybe a property getter) or keep the reference in an instance variable.

Comment: So `(Carpentor*)theCarpentor` isn't a parameter i guess? its just a reference to the `Carpentor` class ? am i correct ?

Comment: No, it's a reference to an instance of the `Carpentor` class.  If your method is static, then you don't need to pass an instance, you can just use `[Carpentor carpentorLoad];`.  It's hard to give you an exact answer without seeing how your objects are actually defined.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming they are the same object, you would call `[self carpentorLoad]`.

If `carpentorLoad` is a member of another class, either call `[<ClassName> carpentorLoad]` or `[<yourObject> carpentorLoad]`, depending on if it is a static or instance method, respectively.

Comment: could you give me an example for `[<yourObject> carpentorLoad]` as in what is `<yourObject>`

Comment: In `- (void)carpentorLoad`, the leading dash means that it is an instance method.

Comment: It is just an object from whichever class has `carpentorLoad`.  And @Bavarious, you're totally right, though given what the method does, OP probably actually wants it to be static.

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, you don't call methods, you *send messages*.  The Obj-C runtime matches your message to a method in the reciever's class or one of its ancestor classes, and then calls the method it finds.